# How to use preg_match in php

Tags: php, regex

Am getting a response that looks like this:

```
response[0] = {Delta=[r3, r4], X=alarmOff, Y=heatOn}
```

and using the `preg_match`
I want to extract from response[0] and get the follwing output

Output:
r3r4

Am trying to extract the output with the following:

```
preg_match('/^{Delta=(\[.*\, .*\])}$/', $response[0], $matches)
```

Am not reaching the desired output

Comment: What is your next question? How to extract the `r3` and `r4` values? Do you need to validate the string or is this purely about extracting/parsing a strictly formatted string? Please explain what you are trying to achieve with this task.  Is this pattern inappropriate for your real data? https://3v4l.org/B9UIM If so, why?

Comment: The string that is coming as a response i have a structure like {Delta=[r3, r4], X=alarmOff, Y=heatOn} but is not always coming with r3 and r4. The values that is coming with are from r1 .. r10 and they are coming {Delta=[ri, rj], X=alarmOff, Y=heatOn} witch i and j are values from 1 to 10. I want to extract ri and rj exactly with this output : rirj . The output that u gave is like that [ri, rj]. Thanks for your anwser.

Comment: Please add **all** clarification to your quesiton by editing it. This should also explain what "facing problems" means

Comment: Someone below gave me the answer, I edited the question though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a negated character class `[^` to rule out the characters that are not allowed to match:

```
{Delta=(\[[^][,]*,[^][]*])[^{}]*}
```

- `{Delta=` Match literally
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\[` Match `[`
  - `[^][,]*,` Match 0+ times any char other than `[` `]` `,` and then match the `,`
  - `[^][]*` Optionally match any char except `[` and `]`
  - `]` Match `]`
- `)` Close group 1
- `[^{}]*` Match 0+ times any char other than `{` and `}`
- `}` Match `}`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oMPp9i/1) | [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/qeIrD)

Example printing the group 1 value:

```
$re = '/{Delta=(\[[^][,]*,[^][]*])[^{}]*}/';
$str = '{Delta=[r3, r4], X=alarmOff, Y=heatOn}';

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);

print_r($matches[1]);
```

Output

```
[r3, r4]
```

---

To get the separate matches for r3 and r4 and get `r3r4` in the result, you can use 2 capture groups:

```
 {Delta=\[([^][,]*),\h*([^][]*)][^{}]*}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8o4FA3/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/AvPiT)

```
$re = '/{Delta=\[([^][,]*),\h*([^][]*)][^{}]*}/';
$str = '{Delta=[r3, r4], X=alarmOff, Y=heatOn}';
$result = preg_replace($re, '$1$2', $str);

echo $result;
```

Output

```
r3r4
```

Comment: I would like the Output to be like that :  r3r4       Is that possible?

Comment: @kolokasi Then you can substitute with the 2 groups, see https://regex101.com/r/8o4FA3/1 I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

use [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to test the regex.

in your code, if you drop off the closing brace and $ the match works and returns the text enclosed in square brackets.

```
$matchText = '' ;
$isMatch = preg_match('/^{Delta=(\[.*\])/', $response[0], $matches)
if ( $isMatch )
{
  $matchText = $matches[1] ;
  echo "got match: $matchText \n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
  $pattern = "/^{Delta=\[(.*)\](.*)$/";
    $response[0] = "/^{Delta=\[(.*)\](.*)$/";
    preg_match($pattern, $response[0], $matches);
    print_r($matches[1]);
```

Comment: Please never post code-only answers on Stack Overflow.